# Remove application from App Store's Update section

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I've got an application in my Updates list which I never installed. It doesn't appear under Purchases nor Hidden Purchases. I can't hide it by right-clicking on it. When I click "Update" it asks me for some different Apple ID I've never heard of.

How can I get rid of the update showing up?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57988/51046) solved it:

> All app downloaded from Mac AppStore(MAS) contain a receipt inside
>   their app bundle (example: appname.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt).
>   MAS will scan this file to check whether the new version is available.
>
> You can use this application (Find Any File) to search any receipt on
>   your drive: http://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/
>
> 1. Launch 'Find Any File' and search for: _MASReceipt
> 2. Go through each result that you think could be the culprit, copy the receipt to your desktop as a backup, and after that delete the
>      receipt inside
>      _MASReceipt folder.
> 3. Open MAS and let it scan for software update. If it's still showing the wrong ID, it means that you've deleted the wrong receipt.
>      Restore the receipt backup from your desktop to it's previous
>      location.
> 4. Repeat the process until you've found the problem receipt.

Answer (score -2):

Or download EasyFind -- free from the Mac App Store -- which will quickly and easily find anything anywhere and belongs in every Mac's dock.

It might help you find the erenasoft related files that the command line answers suggest without needing shell skills.

Answer (score -2):

You have the game 'Galaxy on Fire 2' installed. Remove it from all drives, even external drives. Empty trash, reboot, and go back to app store update, the update will then stop showing.

Answer (score -2):

The grep -r "EnsensaSoft" will not work. It should be:

```
cd /Applications
```

and then

```
ls -ltr | grep -ir EnsensaSoft
```

Answer (score -3):

In Terminal type:

```
cd /Applications
```

then type:

```
grep -r "EnsenaSoft"
```

This will deep search your applications folder for any sign of that application or it's receipt. It could take a while; if any results show up make a note of the path and then you can trash/delete the app.

Hit Control-C anytime during the grep search to cancel it.